# Why does base class object cannot able hold child class object

Tags: c#, .net

when i try to create new child class object and assign it to a base class object ,During compile time it cannot able to find method of child class... , yes base class is not known to all child class methods.

But why base class is able to hold only child class variables with data and why not methods ?

[image]

```
public class baseclass
{
    public string name = string.Empty;
    public void member()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base");
    }
}

public class childclass : baseclass
{
    public string game = string.Empty;
    public new void member()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("child");
    }

    public void testingmethod()
    { Console.WriteLine("child 2"); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        baseclass baseObj = new childclass() { name = "test", game = "test" };
        baseObj.member();
        baseObj.testingmethod();
        baseObj.member(); 

        string str = "abcd";
        Console.WriteLine(str);

        char jat = Convert.ToChar(str.ToCharArray()[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        //ITest obj = new TestClass();
        //obj.TestMethod(); //Way to call implicitely implemented method 

        //ITest obj2 = new TestClass1();
        //obj2.TestMethod();
    }

}
```

As per my understanding for below question new object of `childclass` is stored inside `baseclass`. but why base class obj can able to hold child class object?
The child class is known to base as well as child class . then why child class not able to hold object of base class?

**What is the exact meaning of BaseClass obj = new ChildClass();?**

**why not ChildClass obj2 = new BaseClass(); is not valid ??**

Comment: Side note: if you're just starting out, now is the *ideal* time to learn about and start following naming conventions, before you get into habits with unconventional names.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is called `Inheritance`. One of the four pillar of Object-oriented programming language.

**What is the exact meaning of `BaseClass obj = new ChildClass();` ?**

- It means you are creating an instance of `ChildClass`, using `BaseClass`.
- Here `ChildClass` is inheriting from `BaseClass`, that means `ChildClass` gets all the properties and functions of `BaseClass` automatically. As there **is a** relationship between `BaseClass` and `ChildClass`, we can define instance of `ChildClass` using `BaseClass` type.

---

**why not ChildClass obj2 = new BaseClass(); is not valid ??**

- Because there is no relationship between `BaseClass` with `ChildClass` in the reverse order.
- To define obj2 as of type `ChildClass`, we need **is a** relationship between `ChildClass` and `BaseClass`.

---

Let's take a below example

[image]

Here,

> A Dog is an Animal, Correct?
>
> An Animal is a Dog ????? -> No right, Animal can be Tigar, Lion, Elephant or Dog!

<sup>**Image source:** [Random Google Search.](https://automationtestings.com/is-a-relationship-java/) All credit goes to the image owner</sup>

Comment: BaseClass obj = new ChildClass(); This is still not clear....  **new ChildClass()** We are creating childclass object - memory is created for that object and storing it in base class object . Is it so ?

Comment: *"Compiler will decide the exact type of that instance at run time."* - That's patently false. The compiler determines the type at compile time based on `new childclass()`.

Comment: Yes, we are creating object of `ChildClass`.

Comment: @Srivahgar: It's not storing it *\_in\_* a base class object. It's storing the *reference* to the object in a `baseclass` variable. `obj` can only see the members of the declared type, `baseclass`. You have to cast that to `childclass` to access `childclass` members. A `baseclass` reference to a `childclass` instance is a myopic view of the actual instance, a view that can only see the `baseclass` portion of it.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar: I saw that, but I don't think the revised statement actually contributes anything meaningful or helpful.

Comment: i got it. I can understand inheritance provides reusability,inheritance types etc  but what is the use of having a base class variable storing the reference of child class object .For that we can simply have child class object to store the reference of it right ? @madreflection

Comment: @madreflection, yes you are correct, but here I tried to explain OP `is-a` relationship a one way relationship **not** a two way relationship

Comment: @Srivahgar: The purpose of a base class reference comes into play when you have multiple derived classes and the base class defines virtual members for common operations. Without that, there's little point in it. You can have a reference to any derived class and perform the operations that are common to all such derived classes using a reference to the base class and the virtual members defined there. This is called *"polymorphism"* and it's one of the key components of OOP. Read up on that.

Comment: Yes, you are right... Interfaces actually provides meaning to a abstraction and inheritance....

Comment: @madreflection, why don't you write an answer. It was really helpful for me too to understand *why we use BaseClass as a type to instantiate a DerivedClass?*. I learned something new today. Thanks for your comments. Cheers

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar: Time. I have a high standard for my answers but not the time to put into one that meets that standard right now. Are you saying that you have upwards of 12k rep and a c# silver badge, but these comments were still informative to you? Surely they weren't that good.

Comment: @madreflection, I think your last comment helped OP and it is appropriate answer than what I wrote. I was aware of this concept, but I failed to put it in the sentences. Rest you can judge as you want.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar: Feel free to incorporate it into your answer.

Answer (score -1):

i just copied your code and everything went fine

but in case of rewriting a function in a child object, you will have to change few things in order to be able to call them
first of all in the base class:

```
public virtual void member()

    {

        Console.WriteLine("base");

    }
```

you need the function to set as virtual function in order to change it in the child instance
and in the child instance:

```
public override void member()

    {

        Console.WriteLine("child");

    }
```

you will need to override the function
also it seems like you try to create an array after that or something like that, if you will want to send parameters you will have to change it in the function and then send it in the constructor.
the create function suppose to look like that:

```
baseclass baseObj = new childobj();
```

and then the code suppose to work perfectly!